# React Native: reset animated value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my react native app I made a very simple animated progressbar, problem is I don't know how to reset the animation.

I tried doing the bellow but it didn't work

```
progressValue = 0;
```

How can I reset animation? also why if I do something like const animation = null it says variable its read only (see commented line on my example).

This is whatI have (works except no way to reset animation):

```
const width = Math.round(Dimensions.get('window').width)-30;

    const progressValue = new Animated.Value(0);
    //const animation = null;

    const onStart = (duration ) => 
    {
        const animation = Animated.timing(progressValue, {
            duration: duration,
            toValue: width,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: true,
        }).start();

        
    };

    const onReset = () => 
    {
        //WHAT DO?
    };
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's an reset function Animated provides but my experience with is has been iffy [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.68/animated#reset)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by reseting to you mean to reset the progress bar, then you can just call

```
progressValue.setValue(0);
```

If you want to restart it, then just just call `onStart` after the upper line.